# Why AbstractList class implement set() method

Tags: collections

Why does AbstractList class implements set(int index, E element) method? All it does is, it throws UnsupportedOperationException.

However, All childs of it(ArrayList,LinkedList,Vector) implements(overrides) this method and provides its logic for the operation. Why is this method implemented by AbstactList at all, if all classes extending AbstractList provides its own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done for descendants classes that implement `List` interface.

For example utility `Arrays.ArrayList` class which is created by `asList` method

```
List<Integer> readOnly = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

does not allow to modify the list, so it's `set(int index, E element)` method throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. This default behaviour is implemented in `AbstractList` class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, can you please tell me why Arrays also has ArrayList implementation(inner class), and why it does not uses ArrayLIst of util package?

Comment: @VjMore it is a special class to simplify creating lists from a number of arguments. It does not use java.util.ArrayList because it should be immutable by design